# Python sort files by type and generate html code

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a code that generates some html code for files in different folders, grouped by category, and returns a dictionary with that html code also grouped by category, but the final code doesn't have the files sorted by types. For example:

folder 1 contains : 2 csv files and 1 ppt file

folder 2 contains : 3 csv files

so the html that is generated puts first the items in folder 1 and then 2. I would like to have them sorted by file type. Also, is there a way to eliminate at least one of the `for` loops?

```
my_dic={
    'category_1':['C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder1','C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder2']
}

def generate_html(dic_list_paths=my_dic):

    final_dic = {}
    html_file='<button type="button" class="collapsible">Archivos</button><div class="content">'
    html_images='<button type="button" class="collapsible">Imagenes</button><div class="content">'

    for key, items in dic_list_paths.items():
        name=key

        for item in items:
            for file in os.listdir(item):
                if '~$' not in file and file.endswith(('.csv','pptx')):
                    rel = os.path.join(item, file)

                    ruta = os.path.join(item, file)
                    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(ruta)
                    img = image_logo[file_extension]

                    html_file +=f'<div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch"> <a href="{rel}" download> <p>{file}</p>'               
                    html_file +='</a></div>'

                elif file.endswith('jpg'):

                    html_images +='<div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch"> <picture>'
                    html_images += f'<img src="{file}"'
                    html_images += """ class="lazy card-img-top" """
                    html_images += f'alt="{file}"'
                    html_images +='></picture> </div>'                  

        html_file+='</div>'
        html_images+='</div>'
        code=[html_file,html_images]
        final_dic[name]=code

    return final_dic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the files by extension, you can just use the sorted function on the list before the loop. To merge the files from different folders, do the folder loop first, then the html loop

```
for key, items in dic_list_paths.items():
    name=key

    allfiles=[]  # files from all folders
    for item in items:    # each folder
        for file in os.listdir(item):  # each file in folder
             allfiles += os.path.join(item, file)

    filesSorted = sorted(allfiles, key=lambda s: s[s.index('.'):]+s if '.' in s else s) # sort by extension
    for file in filesSorted:  # file includes path
        if '~$' not in file and file.endswith(('.csv','pptx')):
            rel = ruta = file  
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(ruta)
            img = image_logo[file_extension]

            html_file +=f'<div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch"> <a href="{rel}" download> <p>{file}</p>'               
            html_file +='</a></div>'

        elif file.endswith('jpg'):
            ........
```